# Can't read my "Online archived" mails from EWS?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, office365, exchangewebservices, office365api

We use Office 365.

When I try to get the mails in my shared online archived mailboxes, it returns nothing.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub DownloadEmailFromProperties(userLogin As String, userPassword As String, sharedMailbox As String)
    Dim service As New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013)
    service.Credentials = New WebCredentials(userLogin, userPassword)
    service.Url = New System.Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")

    Dim mb As Mailbox = New Mailbox(sharedMailbox)
    Dim view As ItemView = New ItemView(50, 0, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning)
    view.PropertySet = PropertySet.IdOnly

    Dim results As FindItemsResults(Of Item) = service.FindItems(New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.ArchiveMsgFolderRoot, mb), view)

    MsgBox(results.Count) ' results.count is 0 :(    
End Sub
```

Any suggestions to how I can access my online archived mails throgh EWS?

Answer (score 0):

It appears your only accessing the Root of the Archive Store where generally there would be no content anyway. What you should be doing is FindFolder operation on the Folders in the Archive store (starting at the MsgRoot) then check the item count on the folder (rather then using findItems). You can test this easily using the EWSEditor https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/ without needing to write any code.

You should also be using the TotalCount property on the FindItemsResults class

Cheers
Glen